# Webdatagrid up down arrows edit mode for System.Double make numbers change

Tags: asp.net, infragistics

When editing an integer field the up/down arrows make the number go up and down respectively. Is there a way to stop this behavior?

Comment: what control you are using? what build of NetAdvantage you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a NumericEditorProvider and set the SpinDelta to 0 on the EditorControl.  There are more details on EditorProviders in the NetAdvantage Help:
http://help.infragistics.com/NetAdvantage/ASPNET/Current/CLR4.0/?page=WebDataGrid_Editor_Providers.html